# Is there a way to add the recipient_email field using the composer in Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way to add the recipient_email field using the composer in Freeform. We want the customer to be able to use the composer to edit a form and need to be able to send email notifications based on a dropdown selection field on the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past with JavaScript - dynamically selecting fields etc. This is some example of ways you could do it:

Dynamic recipients:
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#recipients

using JS
[Getting Recipient Names/email address in Notification](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13250/getting-recipient-names-email-address-in-notification)

Composers:
[Freeform and Dynamic Email Recipients](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32341/freeform-and-dynamic-email-recipients)